# Frechet differentiability, RNP, and Asplundness (soft question)

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, banach-spaces

I'm looking for references which provide good surveys and histories of results related to Gateaux and Frechet derivatives and their relationship to Asplundness and RNP. Specifically, any papers or books which explain the underlying ideas and geometry, rather than simply proving results or leaning heavily on other unexplained existence results as a black box.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Namioka and Phelps:

*Namioka, I.; Phelps, R. R.*, [**Banach spaces which are Asplund spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-75-04261-1), Duke Math. J. 42, 735-750 (1975). [ZBL0332.46013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0332.46013).

In this paper the concept "Asplund space" was first proposed, and proofs of the  main properties were given.

Comment: I haven't. I don't have institutional access, so paywalls are a stopper for me.

Comment: It seems, for research in mathematics, math.se is no substitute for a technical library.